# Connecting to db and waiting for http request simultaniusly

Tags: python, pymongo, bottle

I am just starting to program on python,
and wrote this code

```
from bottle import route, run, template
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.tongler

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template("Hello {{name}}", name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8888)

print db
```

but it print db object only after terminating 8888 listener, how can I listen for http requests and perform other operations without waiting the http server termination? How is that done?

Comment: What operations do you want to do?

Comment: Normally if you need to do things independently from one another, you have to use threads or processes. Sometimes you can also use some form of collaborative multi-threading, but I don't know if bottle run method is implemented like this (probably not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you execute that file, the first command to be executed is the `run` method call, which starts a process that blocks the rest of the application from being executed until it is closed.

To use the database, you'd have to perform your database operations either as the result of a request, or somewhere before the `run` method call.

For example, lets say you want to show the records in that database, you might do it like this:

```
@route('/records/<id>')
def show_records(id=None):
    results = db.mycollection.find_one({'id': id})
    return template('Record: {{record}}', record=results)
```